# Firebase Messaging: Can I check if the user already has a token without invoking the browser prompt?

Tags: angular, permissions, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, angularfire

I'm building an Angular **WEB** app which features cloud push notifications with Firebase. I use the AngularFireMessaging service (from the Angular Fire library). At first when the app launches I check if the user has already granted permissions and requested token which can be easily done using the getToken() method. Here's a very short example of what I'm doing:

```
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Injectable()
export class PushNotificationsService {
    constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}

    detectPermissionStatus(): Observable<string> {
        return this.afMessaging.getToken().pipe(
            map(token => { /*.... some code here....*/ })
        );
    }
}
```

If I already have granted permissions and a token is availabe the observable returns it right away and then I do whatever I want. But if I don't have any permission status (for example when I visit the page for the first time) the default browser promp to allow/deny notifications gets invoked. This seems weird to me because I haven't explicitly called the requestPermission() function. It seems that getToken() function also somehow makes the browser to invoke the prompt. This is a behavior that I don't really want since it blocks my app to continue further because I rely on something to be returned (no matter if it's existing token or nothing) in order to proceed with the rest of the requests that I need to do.

So... the short question - is there any way to check if the user has already requested token without invoking the prompt?

**EDIT:**
If you are wondering why on Earth would I need to perform these actions in this way - it's because I want to check if the user has a token right before sending the login request and if a token exists - I send the token along with the login request. Then in the backend I simply check if this user has already been associated with this token (it may happen for multiple users who use the same browser to share one token) and if yes - what is their latest desicion on this subscription (have they opted out of the notifications or not). And I hope you already get the picture - if the prompt window appears the application just hangs and waits for some decision to be made and then we proceed with the login. The only workaround that I can think of right now is to store the token in the local storage and simply get it from there but storing anything in the browser is my last resort.

**EDIT:** 
Another solution that I've found is to use the browser built in Notification api. With Notification.permission I can see the status of the permission (default, denied or granted). If it returns status 'granted' I know that I have a token and I can proceed invoking getToken() from firebase messaging. Otherwise I just skip straight to the login and I'll later invoke the prompt when the user decides to subscribe for notifications.

Comment: investigating the same issue. problem is that getToken.subscribe always brings up the browser popup. there is no checkToken like function. So indeed the native Notification.permission is a great solution.

Comment: I think it was working fine with 5.x but broken in 6.x.

Comment: I also created an issue here https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2328

Answer (score 0):

The other method I find that can be helpful is putting `local-storage` data as true/false. Since Firebase token is following browser.

Then you can run that `local-storage` check and invoke `firebase.messaging.getToken()` function.

Comment: as I mentioned in the original post - using the local storage is the last resort and I would prefer different solutions. Anyway, the solution using `Notification.permission` worked for me just fine. Since I'm not working on this project anymore I don't know what's going on and if this was fixed in the firebase library.